# Задачи по массивам

Tags: алгоритм

Прошу разъяснить данные задачи, но не приводить их решения. В первой задачи мне непонятно, что имеется ввиду "каждый раз уменьшая на 1 количество анализируемых элементов", а в 2-й эта часть "их первые вхождения."

> Задачи:
>
> 1. Дан массив A размера N. Упорядочить его по возрастанию методом сортировки простым выбором: найти максимальный элемент массива и поменять его местами с последним элементом; выполнить описанные действия N – 1 раз, каждый раз уменьшая на 1 количество анализируемых элементов и выводя содержимое массива.
> 2. Дан целочисленный массив размера N. Удалить из массива все одинаковые элементы, оставив их первые вхождения.

Answer (score 1):

1. Тут приводится алгоритм простой сортировки. Просматриваем весь массив, находим максимальный элемент. Меняем его местами с последним элементом массива. Проделан первый этап сортировки: теперь у нас в последней ячейке находится максимальный элемент, который и должен там в результате находиться. Итак, в последнюю ячейку положено то, что нужно. Теперь  то же проделать с оставшимися элементами, т.е. с элементами с индексами от 0 до N -1. И т.д., пока весь массив не будет упорядочен.
2. Вхождения какого-то значения - это конкретный элемент массива, ячейка, содержащая это значение. Т.е. нужно оставить первые ячейки с повторяющимся значением.

Comment: Насчет второй задачи:
Исходный массив: 1 3 4 1 1
Результат: 1 3 4 (первую единицу оставили, другие удалили) 
Примерно так это выглядит?

Comment: @miki... (сами продолжайте). В п.1 определитесь, толи "от 0 до N-2", толи "от 1 до N-1", иначе ошибка. (Весьма распространённая ошибка "+-1")
@ArniLand в задаче 2 вам надо использовать какую-то структуру (достаточно множества, для отслеживания, что такой элемент уже встречался). Если он был -- удаляете (или сдвигом хвоста, если работаете с массивом "по месту", или некопированием, если копируете в новый массив). Если не использовать доп.множество, то для каждого следующего элемента придётся просматривать результирующий массив на предмет дублирования. Мог бы пояснить текстом, если надо.

Comment: @alexlz, абсолютно верное замечание. Если индексация начинается с 0, то первый проход от 0 до N-1, второй от 0 до N-2 и т.д. @ArniLand, вроде бы, именно так и должно быть.